# Type Error page.tsx has an invalid "default" export

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, deployment, vercel

While I was deploying my project in vercel I have a problem Type error: Page "app/(root)/form/new/page.tsx"  has an invalid "default" export: Type "FormProps" is not valid. Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1 but upon checking I have export default on that specific page

```
interface FormProps {
    initialData: Informations | null;
}


const formSchema = z.object({
    fullname: z.string().min(2, {
        message: 'Fullname is required'
    }),
    contactEmail: z.string().min(2, {
        message: 'Email is Required'
    }),
    address: z.string().min(2, {
        message: 'Address is Required'
    }),
    contactNumber: z.string().min(11, {
        message: 'Contact Number is required'
    }),
    serialNumber: z.string().min(20, {
        message: 'Serial Number must be 20 Character'
    }),
    productCategory: z.string().min(2, {
        message: 'Product Category is required'
    }),
    warrantyStatus: z.string().min(2, {
        message: 'Warranty is required'
    }),
    desc: z.string().min(10, {
        message: 'Problem Description is required'
    }),
    store: z.string().min(10, {
        message: 'Problem Description is required'
    }),
    productModel: z.string().min(10, {
        message: 'productModel is required'
    }),
    imagePath: z.string().min(10, {
        message: 'Image upload is required'
    }),
    dateOfPurchase: z.date()
})


const font = Montserrat({
    weight: '600',
    subsets: ['latin']
})


export default function RepairForm({
    initialData
}: FormProps) {

    const [date, setDate] = React.useState<Date>()
    const { toast } = useToast();
    const router = useRouter();

    const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
        resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
        defaultValues: initialData || {
            fullname: '',
            contactEmail: '',
            address: '',
            contactNumber: '',
            serialNumber: '',
            productCategory: '',
            warrantyStatus: '',
            desc: '',
            imagePath: '',
            dateOfPurchase: undefined,
            productModel: '',
            store: ''
        }
    })
```

can anyone help me? Thanks

Changing data types in formProps and still ddint fix my problem

Comment: Can you show the code inside  `app/(root)/form/new/page.tsx`? You can edit your question.

Comment: hi sir im new at stackoverflow it seems i cant import my code needs formating?